# void operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle{
public:
 Circle(){ cout<<"im a circle\n"; }
 void operator+(){ cout<<"im a + operator\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Circle();
  Circle();
  + 
  Circle();
}
```

output

> "im a circle"
>
> "im a circle"
>
> "im a circle"
>
> "im a + operator"

**i want to receive output with this order**

> "im a circle"
>
> "im a circle"
>
> "im a + operator"
>
> "im a circle"

I want as third output `im a + operator`.
How can I fix this code so the output is in this specific order?

Comment: _`+ //void operator plus called`_ Huh??

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile because there is no `operator()` defined. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DieterLücking Ah, yes. There's a unary `operator+()`.

Comment: guys im sorry,code fixed check again..

Comment: @therealp _"code fixed"_ That's even worse.

Comment: @therealp A `Circle` instance needs to be constructed first before you can invoke `operator+` on it. Perhaps you're looking for `Circle a, b; +a; Circle c;` or `Circle(); +Circle(); Circle();`

Comment: There is thus no way to get this print order?

Answer (score 1):

To get the output wanted just write

```
int main()
{
  Circle a;
  Circle b;
  +a; 
  Circle c;
}
```

See a [working demo](http://ideone.com/Gmh4oe).

Comment: thanks! but is necessary to give only the "+" operator without a;

Comment: @therealp That's not a valid c++ expression, thus you are lost. Why is this needed actually? You can't call an operator without a concrete instance.

Comment: @therealp Oh, I'm surprised now. May be you could add another answer that shows how you actually fixed your code achieving the requirement stated in your 1st comment? I'm just curious.